# Mocha test case - are nested it( ) functions kosher?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, jasmine, mocha.js

I have this case where I think I want to have nested `it()` test cases in a Mocha test. I am sure this is wrong, and I don't see any recommendations to do what I am doing, but I don't really know of a better way at the moment -

basically, I have a "parent" test, and inside the parent test there's a forEach loop with all the "child" tests:

```
it('[test] enrichment', function (done) {

        var self = this;

        async.each(self.tests, function (json, cb) {

            //it('[test] ' + path.basename(json), function (done) {

                var jsonDataForEnrichment = require(json);
                jsonDataForEnrichment.customer.accountnum = "8497404620452729";
                jsonDataForEnrichment.customer.data.accountnum = "8497404620452729";
                var options = {
                    url: self.serverURL + ':' + self.serverPort + '/event',
                    json: true,
                    body: jsonDataForEnrichment,
                    method: 'POST'
                };


               request(options,function (err, response, body) {
                    if (err) {
                        return cb(err);
                    }

                     assert.equal(response.statusCode, 201, "Error: Response Code");
                     cb(null);


                });

            //});

        }, function complete(err) {
            done(err)
        });

    });
```

as you can see, two separate lines are commented out - I want to include them so that I can easily see the results of each separate test, but then I have this awkward situation of firing the callback for the test alongside the callback for async.each.

Has anyone seen this time of situation before and know of a good solution where the tester can easily see the results of each test in a loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Don't nest `it` calls. Call them synchronously.**

Nested `it` calls are never okay in Mocha. Nor are `it` calls performed asynchronously. (The *test* can be asynchronous, but you cannot *call* `it` asynchronously.) Here's a simple test:

```
describe("level 1", function () {
    describe("first level 2", function () {
        it("foo", function () {
            console.log("foo");
            it("bar", function () {
                console.log("bar");
            });
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            it("created async", function () {
                console.log("the asyncly created one");
            });
        }, 500);
    });

    describe("second level 2", function () {
        // Give time to the setTimeout above to trigger.
        it("delayed", function (done) {
            setTimeout(done, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

If you run this you won't get the nested test `bar` will be ignored and the test created asynchronously (`delayed`) will also be ignored.

**Mocha has no defined semantics for these kinds of calls.** When I ran my test with the latest version of Mocha at the time of writing (2.3.3), it just ignored them. I recall that an earlier version of Mocha would have recognized the tests but would have attached them to the wrong `describe` block.

Answer (score 4):

I think the need for dynamic tests are relatively common (data-driven tests?), and there is common use for dynamic `it` and test cases.

I think it could be easier to manage testcase completion if tests could be executed in series.  This way you wouldn't have to worry about managing nested async `done`'s.  Since `request` is async (i'm assuming), your test cases will still mainly be executing concurrently.

```
describe('[test] enrichment', function () {

        var self = this;


        _.each(self.tests, function (json, cb) {

            it('[test] ' + path.basename(json), function (done) {

                var jsonDataForEnrichment = require(json);
                jsonDataForEnrichment.customer.accountnum = "8497404620452729";
                jsonDataForEnrichment.customer.data.accountnum = "8497404620452729";
                var options = {
                    url: self.serverURL + ':' + self.serverPort + '/event',
                    json: true,
                    body: jsonDataForEnrichment,
                    method: 'POST'
                };


               request(options,function (error, response, body) {
                    if (error) {
                        cb(error);

                    }
                    else{
                        assert.equal(response.statusCode, 201, "Error: Response Code");
                        cb(null);
                    }

                    done(); 
                });

            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: one problem with using a describe( ) as the parent instead of an it ( ), is that the context for the callback is different. Nested it( ) is better because 'this' will refer to the same thing..kinda hard to explain

Comment: ok, you're right, nested it( ) s cause problems, not doing that