# Running async code before 'describe' in Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to generate tests dynamically using a for-loop, but the number of tests to generate is obtained from a async task. Here is my code:

```
var noOfTestsToRun;

before(function() {
    return someAsyncTask().then(function(result) {
        noOfTestsToRun = result;
    })
});

describe('My Test Suite', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfTestsToRun; i++) {
        it('Test ' + i, function() {
            //...
        });
    }
});
```

However, `noOfTestsToRun = result` doesn't seem to be executed when it reaches the `for` loop.

I was wondering if there are any solutions to this kind of problems. Thank you.

Comment: Mehdi, the link above is about running async task before all 'it', mine is about running async task before 'describe'

Comment: Louis, it works, thank you very much. But one more question, what if I want some async task to be executed before a `describe` within another `describe`?

Comment: Execute the async code first, then define all the `mocha` stuff, like the `before`, `describe` and all.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `done` callback to your `before` function.

```
var noOfTestsToRun;

before(function(done) {
    return someAsyncTask().then(function(result) {
        noOfTestsToRun = result;

        // Complete the async stuff
        done();
    })
});

describe('My Test Suite', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfTestsToRun; i++) {
        it('Test ' + i, function() {
            //...
        });
    }
});
```

When your async task is finished and `done()` is called, we are telling Mocha that the async stuff is finished and it can move on to the expectations.

**UPDATE**

So, your goal is to have mocha run your dynamic tests.

You can achieve that with a bit of a hack. You will need an `it` block to force `before` to execute. And within the before, you can dynamically generate `it` tests based on your asynchronous result.

```
before(function() {
    return someAsyncTask().then(function(result) {
        describe('My Test Suite (dynamic)', function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < result; i++) {
                it('Test ' + i, function() {
                    // ...
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

it('should force before to execute', function() {
    console.log('Hack to force before to execute');
});
```

[Working pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKAmxb)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But it is not working.

I've replaced `someAsyncTask()` with `Promise.resolve(1)` and tried your solution. `noOfTestsToRun` is still undefined when it reaches the `for` loop

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465431/how-can-i-dynamically-generate-test-cases-in-javascript-node

Comment: The solution above has a constant value `['nl', 'fr', 'de']` for the `forEach` to generate tests. Mine needs a value from a async task. It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Actually, the answer below the approved answer was the one that would work for you. I have updated the answer here for you.

Comment: Both code snippets in this answer are wrong. The first one uses the `done` callback *and* returns a promise. It is unnecessary to use the `done` callback when returning promises. The 2nd code snippet calls `describe` and `it` from inside `before`. That's something that Mocha does not support. A tiny demo will *seem* to work but a full-fledged suite trying to use the same technique will execute tests in an unexpected way.

Comment: Mocha documentation says nesting `it` calls is a no-no. [S.O thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749262/mocha-test-case-are-nested-it-functions-kosher)

Comment: In modern environments you can do a top level `await` to get async data, as documented here https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests